# Adobe Flex Tabbed View Navigator Mobile Application Embedded Font

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe, font-face

I have a TabbedViewNavigatorApplication, I am using an embeded font for my tabs however when a tab is selected it loses the embeded font as by default the selected item is italic (I believe).  I've tried several different styles but have not been able to figure out what style applies to the selected tab in my tabbedviewnavigator.  Thanks in advance for the help.

JH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy-paste your embedding declaration( `@font-face`), add there `fontStyle: italic`, and change url of embedded file to version that contains italic font faces. (usually it is ended with `i`, like `verdanai.tff`.

You can also do this for `fontWeight: bold`, and for any other variations of font.
All of your font-faces shall have similar `fontFamily` name - in that case correct version of font will be chosen automatically.

Comment: How do you specify that the tab use the italic version when selected?

Comment: Don't know, I just suggest you to embed of variants of fonts. In that case when tab will be italic or bold, it will still use embedded font.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it working...  It was a bit of a pain and I'm sure could have been done in an easier way but here's what I did.

1. Downloaded FontCreator 7
2. Opened my regular (non-italic) font
3. Selected "Font" > "Properties"
4. Set it to Italic (only changes properties of the file, not how the font looks)
5. Save my font
6. Embed the font with fontStyle: italic;
7. Set the fontStyle:italic on the TabbedViewNavigator and set the font family to my embeded italic font